# Show two sets are two bases for the same subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

A question asks me to show that {[1,1,1,0]}, {[2,0,1,0]} and {[8,4,6,0]}, {[5,1,3,0]} are two bases for the same subspace of R^4.

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly. What I did was show that the two bases span the same subspace by putting them in a matrix and reducing it to row echelon form. I concluded that since the system is consistent, the two span the same substance. However I'm not sure that that is the correct procedure, as my professor noted that what I said is that the span of the 2nd two vectors is continued in the span of the first two. What does that mean, and how is it different from what I concluded?

I've read through this:
[determine whether the sets span the same subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47625/linear-algebra-determine-whether-the-sets-span-the-same-subspace/%22determine%20whether%20the%20sets%20span%20the%20same%20subspace%22)
and this: [Prove two sets span the same subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049238/prove-two-sets-span-the-same-subspace)

From this, I understand that to show that the first set spans the second, I solve for a[1,1,1,0] + b[2,0,1,0] = [8,4,6,0] and a[1,1,1,0] + b[2,0,1,0] = [5,1,3,0]. Is that correct? Is this the same thing that I did with matrix procedure mentioned above?

For my example specifically, after I use the above to show that they span, do I then just show linear independence of both sets individually? Does having that both sets are linear independent and span of one subset is contained in the other suffice?

Thank you

Comment: Both sets are LI trivially, because they contain only two vectors which are not multiples of each other. I believe the way to show they span the same subspace is to show that each vector in the second basis is a linear combination of the vectors in the first basis. Do this by constructing two augmented matrices, $[ \vec{a}_1 \vec{a}_2 \| \vec{b}_1]$ and $[\vec{a}_1 \vec{a}_2 \| \vec{b}_2]$ and showing these are both consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write each vector in the second set as linear combinations of the vectors in the first.

$[5,1,3,0] = [1,1,1,0] + 2[2,0,1,0]$

$[8,4,6,0] = 4[1,1,1,0]+2[2,0,1,0]$.

Therefore the subspace spanned by the second set of vectors is contained in the subspace spanned by the first.

But as Rob noted in his comment, each of these subspaces are 2-dimensional. The only way to have a 2-dimensional subspace contained in a 2-dimensional subspace is for them to be equal.